# Assets in public folder not loading when browsing CRUD pages of a class in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra

I am using Bootstrap for some basic styling to a CRUD app in Sinatra. While the assets in the public folder load as usual on all pages, they don't load when I am browsing a particular record in my database.

For example, `http://localhost:4567/songs` loads all stylesheets and assets, but not `http://localhost:4567/songs/1`.

In my console, the page seems to be trying to find the css file in /songs folder, which I am not sure why its doing that.

```
http://localhost:4567/songs/bootstrap.css
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

My main.rb file: http://pastie.org/8543319

My song.rb class file: http://pastie.org/8543312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide absolute path for assets in your views.

Comment: Could you give an example? I currently have this asset path in my layout.slim file: link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"

Comment: Add slash "/bootstrap.css"